# GridSearchCV for DecisionTreeClassifier in sklearn randomly generates UndefinedMetricWarning on macOS and Linux but not Windows

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am running into an issue after transferring a grid search workflow for decision tree classifiers from Windows to our Linux cluster. While it works every time on Windows most often than not it generates an error/warning.
The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer,accuracy_score,recall_score,f1_score, precision_score, roc_auc_score
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
data = pd.read_csv("Dtree_test_data.csv")
d_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
scoring = {'accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
       'precision' : make_scorer(precision_score, average = 'weighted'),
       'recall' : make_scorer(recall_score, average = 'weighted'), 
       'f1_score' : make_scorer(f1_score, average = 'weighted')}
features = data[["H-Bonds","Mass"]]
labels = data["Class"]
parameters = {'max_depth':np.arange(1,3,1),
              'min_samples_leaf': np.arange(0.01,0.05,0.01),
              'min_impurity_decrease':np.arange(0.01,0.04,0.01),
              'criterion':['gini','entropy']}

dtree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = GridSearchCV(dtree,parameters,verbose=1,n_jobs=12,scoring=scoring,refit=False,return_train_score=True,cv=2)
clf.fit(features,labels)
```

The data looks like this:

```
   H-Bonds  Mass  Class
0        2   123      0
1        3    45      1
2        1   153      2
3        4    90      0
4        6   300      1
5        1    40      2
6        2   200      0
7        3   245      1
8        4    87      2
9        1   126      1
```

The error/warning is the following (repeated multiple times):

```
    Fitting 2 folds for each of 48 candidates, totalling 96 fits
/../miniconda3/envs/ml-debug-current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:1334: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
  _warn_prf(average, modifier, msg_start, len(result))
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: Are the versions of sklearn and Python the same in both environments? What are the versions in use? Sometimes sklearn adds new warnings.